# Laravel minimum date requirements

Tags: laravel, date, validation, laravel-validation

Laravel give ma an error "**SSQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '0500-01-01 00:00:00'**" when i input data as  January 1, 500. Even though it is long past, I would like to know the **minimum dat**e.

I want to accept the first date of the calendar. Like: 1/1/0001

Comment: Improve your question, it will get downvotes not an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per MySQL docs, *"MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'"*

The format you are using is wrong, you need to

```
$date = $request->input('date'); // or your date 
$formattedDate = Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Now you can store this `$formattedDate`

And when you are retrieving, you need to format that again to the format you wish.

For that either you could format it where you need to or you could also define an accessor for that. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

However, if you are using an older version of laravel, please refer to docs of that version, because laravel 9 has a new way of accessing the accessor

Reference: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATETIME,both%20date%20and%20time%20parts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20retrieves%20and%20displays%20DATETIME,both%20date%20and%20time%20parts).

Comment: Is it possible to take values outside this range?